# How to make a prediction with an existing model in keras?

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, cnn

I have a pretrained model that i need to load and make a prediction on two images with. The model is a CNN that takes as input 150x150 RGB images and predicts whether it's a cat or a dog. I've sorted out the tensor formatting and model loading, but the result of the prediction looks off and i cant seem to shed light on what the problem is.

My code below:

```
import keras
import cv2
import os
import numpy
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


def loadAndReshape(path):
    targetImage = cv2.imread(path)
    targetImage = cv2.cvtColor(targetImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    targetImage = cv2.resize(targetImage, dsize=(150, 150)) / 255
    targetImage = targetImage.reshape(150, 150, 3).astype('float32')
    return targetImage

li = []
li.append(loadAndReshape('.//test1.jpg'))
li.append(loadAndReshape('.//test2.jpg'))
targetImages = numpy.array(li)

model = None
targetDatagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
targetGenerator = targetDatagen.flow(targetImages, batch_size=2)

if os.path.exists('./Model_cats_dogs_small_dataset.h5'):
    model = keras.models.load_model('./Model_cats_dogs_small_dataset.h5')
    result = model.predict_generator(targetGenerator, steps=2)
    resultSecond = model.predict(targetImages)
    print(f'result: {result} and resultSecond: {resultSecond}')
```

The original model used generators for prediction so i went ahead and used both `predict_generator` and `predict` methods to see the differences.
I was expecting that having 2 images and a binary classifier, the prediction result will be an array containing 2 arrays, each with the probabilities for each class. However, for each prediction i just get only one value for each image, like this: `result: [[0.17093319] [0.170154  ]] and resultSecond: [[0.47771692] [0.99125683]]`

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix this?

Comment: It seems that the last layer has one Neuron and a Sigmoid Fn. You can make it two Neurons and Softmax.

Comment: If i change the number of neurons in the output layer to 2, i get the following error `logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 2) vs (None, 1))`

Comment: One Hot encode _i.e. [ [1,  0], [0, 1] ]_ the target. It is label encoded _i.e. [1, 0 ]_ it seems